# Do we have long-term deposits of vitamins other than vitamin B12 and vitamin D in the body (i.e. deposits lasting for years)?

Tags: vitamin-d, vitamin-b, vitamin-e

Throughout the years, I have only found material about [Vitamin B12 tests](https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/vitamin-b12-test) and about [Vitamin D tests](https://www.webmd.com/diet/vitamin-d-deficiency) but I don't recall **randomly** reading anything about tests for the levels of other vitamins.

Do clinicians normally only check for Vitamin D and Vitamin B12 (or indirectly in [Methyl Malonic Acid / MMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylmalonic_acid)) but not for other vitamins? If so, why is this the case?
Do we have long-term deposits of vitamins other than vitamin B12 and vitamin D in the body (i.e. deposits lasting for years)?

- Mount Sinai hospital in United States of America seems to me to perform [vitamin A tests](https://www.labcorp.com/tests/070140/vitamin-e-and-tocopherol).
- From labcorp website I understand that [vitamin E tests](https://www.labcorp.com/tests/070140/vitamin-e-and-tocopherol) are also possible

But what I am trying to understand is why it's so rare to test for vitamins if they are not `B12` or `D`? (what is the popularity of B12 and D based upon?)
Is it because that humans only have long-lasting deposits of several years only of these two vitamins and not others? Or is it another reason?